# What are getClientRect(); method and layer.children.each do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, konvajs

How does the getClientRect(); method work in this code? Is that mean to get the sides of the rectangle?
Also, what is layer.children.each in the code below? Is that mean selecting each child of the node? Can anyone explain to me how these methods work? I checked the document but still not getting how they work.

Thank you so much for your help! I was able to solve this problem.

```js
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  container: 'container'
});
var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

layer.on('dragmove', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  var targetRect = e.target.getClientRect();
  layer.children.each(function(obj) {
    if (obj === target) {
      return;
    }
    if (haveIntersection(obj.getClientRect(), targetRect)) {
      alert("Intersection")
    }    
  });
});

function haveIntersection(r1, r2) {
  return !(
    r2.x > r1.x + r1.width/2 ||
    r2.x + r2.width/2 < r1.x ||
    r2.y > r1.y + r1.height/2 ||
    r2.y + r2.height/2 < r1.y
  );
}

// This will draw the image on the canvas.
function drawImage(source, konvaImage) {
  layer.add(konvaImage);
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = source;
  image.onload = function() {
    konvaImage.image(image);
    layer.draw();
  }
}


//1yen
var ichiYenImg = new Konva.Image({
  x: 20,
  y: 20,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  draggable: true
});
var sourceImg1 = "https://illustrain.com/img/work/2016/illustrain09-okane5.png";
drawImage(sourceImg1, ichiYenImg);


var goYenImg = new Konva.Image({
  x: 120,
  y: 20,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  draggable: true
});
var sourceImg2 = "https://illustrain.com/img/work/2016/illustrain09-okane7.png";
drawImage(sourceImg2, goYenImg);

//piggy bank 1yen
var ichiYenpiggyImg = new Konva.Image({
  x: 300,
  y: 100,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  draggable: false
});
var sourceImg7 = "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31402838/63416628-a322b080-c3b4-11e9-96e8-e709ace70ec1.png";
drawImage(sourceImg7, ichiYenpiggyImg);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@4.0.5/konva.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="stage-parent">
    <div id="container"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `layer` may have several children elements. So `layer.children` is just an array with of such objects.

`layer.children.each(func)` is a function similar to [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
. It allows to to executre a function for every element in `children` array.

`node.getClientRect()` is a function that calcualte absolute boudning box of any `Konva.Node`. Bounding box is just an object like this:

```
{
   x: 10,
   y: 10,
   width: 60,
   height: 60
}
```

It allows you to detect the position and the size of any object, even if it is scaled, rotate, etc. Usually, that function can be used to defined position f edges of the shapes.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to response! What does () in obj.getClientRect()? Why this is empty parentheses?

Comment: The getClientRect() function is a method of various objects in Konva. For example, in the line `var targetRect = e.target.getClientRect();`  we are asking for a rect that defines the box containing the e.target shape. getClientRect() does not need call parameters, so the brackets are empty.